# Joining two lists together in a weird way

Tags: c#, linq

I have this problem that I think I can do with LINQ but I'm not sure how.

I have two lists previous and current. Previous is a list of custom objects that I made after I make a call Process.GetProcesses(). Current is what is returned from Process.GetProcesses() at that moment in time.

What I want to do is for any object in the current list that has the same ID as the previous list, put it in list C. If there is an item in the previous list that is not in the current, don't put it in C. If there is an item in list current that is not in previous, but that object in that list (different object than the ones that were made in list previous).

The reason I want to do this is because the time to create those objects from current takes forever, and I just want to save them if they've already been made, but I still need an updated list.

Example

`List A: { {ID: 1, Data1: a1, Data2: a1}, {ID: 2, Data1: a2, Data2: a2}, {ID: 3, Data1: a3, Data2: a3}`

```
List B: { {ID: 1, Stuff: s1}, {ID: 2, Stuff: s2}, {ID: 4, Stuff: s4}}
```

Do some magic...

```
List C: { {ID: 1, Data1: a1, Data2: a1}, {ID: 2, Data1: a2, Data2: a2}, {ID: 4, Stuff: s4}
```

My idea was to use some sort of right join on these two, but I was not sure. Bonus points if during that join, I could create the new object for ID: 4 on the spot instead of iterating the new list for those types of object to update to my custom object.

Comment: Asuming A is previous, B is current, and C is C: 
Inner Join list A and B, to get what you need to add into C. Then merge B into A, to get the new value A should contain.

Comment: At the end of the day, LINQ is about doing DB Query Language like actions on any two collections in memory. So you can mostly view them as 3 Database Tables/Result sets.

Answer (score 0):

1 Build a hashtable for List A by ID. (HashA)
2 Go over elements in list B. If HashA contains element ID, use the object from List A (here: retrieved from hashtable), otherwise, use current element).

Answer (score 0):

```
var lc = la.Where( a => lb.Any( b => b.ID == a.ID ))
            .Select( a => new {ID = a.ID, Data1 = a.Data1, Data2 = a.Data2, Stuff = (string) null})
            .Concat( lb.Where( b => !la.Any( a => a.ID == b.ID )).
                    Select( b => new {ID = b.ID, Data1 = (string)null, Data2 = (string)null, Stuff = b.Stuff}));
```

## Test

```
var la = new [] { new {ID = 1, Data1= "a1", Data2= "a1"}, new {ID= 2, Data1= "a2", Data2= "a2"}, new {ID= 3, Data1= "a3", Data2= "a3"}};
var lb = new [] { new {ID= 1, Stuff= "s1"}, new {ID= 2, Stuff= "s2"}, new  {ID= 4, Stuff= "s4"}};

var lc = la.Where( a => lb.Any( b => b.ID == a.ID ))
            .Select( a => new {ID = a.ID, Data1 = a.Data1, Data2 = a.Data2, Stuff = (string) null})
            .Concat( lb.Where( b => !la.Any( a => a.ID == b.ID )).
                    Select( b => new {ID = b.ID, Data1 = (string)null, Data2 = (string)null, Stuff = b.Stuff}));

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(lc, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true}));
```

Output

```
[
 {"ID": 1, "Data1": "a1", "Data2": "a1", "Stuff": null},
 {"ID": 2, "Data1": "a2", "Data2": "a2", "Stuff": null },
 {"ID": 4, "Data1": null, "Data2": null, "Stuff": "s4" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list where the ID's in both lists match.

Then concat the new list with the current list where the current ID's don't exist in the previous list:

```
var previous = new[]
{
    new Data{ID = 1, Data1 = "a1", Data2 = "a1" },
    new Data{ID = 2, Data1 = "a2", Data2 = "a2" },
    new Data{ID = 3, Data1 = "a3" },
};

var current = new[]
{
    new Data{ID = 1, Stuff = "s1" },
    new Data{ID = 2, Stuff = "s2" },
    new Data{ID = 4, Stuff = "s4" },
};

var newList = previous.Join(current, p => p.ID, c => c.ID, (p, c) => p);

newList = newList.Concat(current.Where(c => !previous.Any(p => p.ID == c.ID)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the items from `previous` that have a matching item in `current`, and then `Concat` those with all the items in `current` that don't have a match in `previous` using `Linq`:

```
var listC = previous
    .Where(p => current.Any(c => c.ID == p.ID))
    .Concat(current.Where(c => previous.All(p => p.ID != c.ID)));
```